# Convenient way to select 100+ columns (but not ALL the table columns) in SQL query at a time?

Tags: sql, metaprogramming, dynamic-sql, dolphindb

I have a table with more than 100 columns and I want to query all but the first and second columns. How do I do it quickly without enumerating 100 columns?

Just for illustrative purposes, suppose I have this table of 6 columns:

```
t = table(1..3 as col1, 1..3 as col2, 1..3 as col3, 1..3 as col4, 1..3 as col5, 1..3 as col6)
t
```

output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
1       1       1       1       1       1
2       2       2       2       2       2
3       3       3       3       3       3
```

How do I select all but the first 2 columns from the table?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the DolphinDB metaprogramming helpful in your case ([metaprogramming technique in DolphinDB](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/meta_programming.md)).

Continuing your example, try this script:

```
colNames = t.schema().colDefs.name
// assuming you don't want col1 and col2
select_cols = colNames[at(!(colNames in [`col1, `col2]))]
res = sql(sqlCol(select_cols), t).eval()
```

Print res:

```
col3    col4    col5    col6
1       1       1       1
2       2       2       2
3       3       3       3
```